# If Cursor is in Location

Tags: c#, position, cursor

```
if (Cursor.Position == closeButton.Location)
{
    closeButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 231, 76, 60);
}
```

This if statement doesn't work for some reason, any help?

I would like it to check if the Cursor position is in the Location set.

Comment: done @S.Akbari :) thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for [`ClientRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your button. So this is the proper syntax to use:

```
if (closeButton.ClientRectangle.Contains(closeButton.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
{
    closeButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 231, 76, 60);
}
```